# wpa_cli setting debugging level

Tags: debugging

How do I increase the debugging level of an already running wpa_supplicant instance?

Every attempt of using wpa_cli level result in a FAIL error message (even pre-selecting the interface with -i when invoking wpa_cli)

Answer (score 5):

There is a typo in the previous answer. It should be like this:

```
 $ sudo wpa_cli log_level debug
 Selected interface 'wlan0'
 OK
 $
```

You can check it with:

```
$ sudo wpa_cli log_level
Selected interface 'wlan0'
Current level: DEBUG
Timestamp: 0
$
```

Comment: Hi@Traut, when I execute the command always get the timestamp value is 0. Please help me. When get the timestamp value.

Comment: @SakthivelAppavu Judging from https://gist.github.com/penguinpowernz/1d36a38af4fac4553562410e0bd8d6cf, you can set `timestamp` value with `sudo wpa_cli log_level <log_level> <timestamp>`. Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

You can change the level to

```
EXCESSIVE, MSGDUMP, DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR
```

with:

```
sudo wpa_cli log_level [level]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use wla_cli log_level debug (or other level) to change te debugging level of an already running wpa_supplicant.

Comment: `sudo wpa_cli level debug` results in a single `FAIL` message.